# How to get layer variables using QGIS Python APIs?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, api, qgis-variable

How can I access the layer variables defined by the user from QGIS Python APIs?

[image: QGIS Layer Variable]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the [QgsExpressionContextUtils()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsExpressionContextUtils.html) class.

More in detail, you may set a new layer variable in this way:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # or similar way for loading a layer
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setLayerVariable(layer,'your_variable', 'John')
```

where `layer` is the layer object, `your_variable` is the name of the variable and `John` is the value of the variable.

For retrieving the value of the layer variable, you can use the following line:

```
QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer).variable('your_variable')
```

In fact, if you run:

```
test = QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(layer).variable('your_variable')
print test
```

you will get:

```
John
```

as desired.